# How can I access the last item in a DataList in order to set its class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create buttons for each item in a DataList, but the last button needs to be formatted differently, so it needs a different css class applied to it.

I think this should be done in the OntemDataBound method, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

I want to do something like this:

```
protected void dlDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemIndex == dlDataList.Items.Count - 1) //This doesn't work like I'd hoped
  {
    Panel button = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("btnButton");
    button.CssClass = ("altClass");
  }
  ...
}
```

The problem is, I don't think the datalist knows how many items it will have in the ItemDataBound event because dlDataList.Items.Count is always the same as the ItemIndex.

Any ideas on how I can give the last button the altClass css class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you bind the DataList, save the total number of items in a page level variable. Then on your ItemDataBound, check to see if the current index is equal to the total items (-1 of course) and set your css class accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<= DataList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (e.Item[i] == dlDataList.Items.Count - 1) //This doesn't work like I'd hoped
     {
       Panel button = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("btnButton");
        button.CssClass = ("altClass");
      }
}
```

Comment: plused ;D. but i changed some lines

Answer (score 0):

Usually index are zero based, so in a list with 5 elements the index of the last element will be 4 and the count 5 so if you subtract 1 from the count I think it will work

Comment: Right, I forgot to put the -1 in when I wrote that sample code. But the value of dlDataList.Items.Count changes with each row, so that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the DataList's DataSource instead of it's items since the items are created just before they are databound.

```
protected void dlDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         // use the item's DataItem property or the DataList's DataSource property directly
         DataTable tbl = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row.Table;
         if (e.Item.ItemIndex == tbl.Rows.Count - 1)
         {
             // ....
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ItemDataBound event is being fired for every object in your data source. So every time an item is added to the data list it's index is 1 higher but also your count, so they are equal constantly. You should do your comparison with the data list data source property and get a count from that. The data source has predetermined knowledge of how big your list will be. You just need to cast the data source as an object that it is data bound to.
So if it is a `List<string>` you would use something like:

`if (e.Item.ItemIndex == ((List<string>)dlDataList.DataSource).Count - 1)`

Comment: dlDataList.DataSource is null in the ItemDataBound event, but I used this in the Selected event of the datasource to store the number of rows returned.

Comment: It's not null in my tests, but I'm not sure how you're binding your data. Glad it was useful anyway.